# Does 連用形 always reflect the meaning of 連体形 of a verb?

Tags: morphology, semantics

The verb [調べる](http://tangorin.com/general/%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B) means

> to examine;  to investigate;  to check up;  to sense;  to study;  to inquire;  to search

The 連用形 [調べ](http://tangorin.com/general/%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9) means

> 1. investigation;  inspection;  examination
> 2. tune;  note;  melody

In this case, why does 連用形 have meanings (tune, note, melody) that are not related to 連体形?

Comment: Instead of 連体形, I think 終止形 or 辞書形 is the right word here. Do you mind if I edit your question?

Comment: You need a better dictionary. See sense 2 here: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B-535605#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88. Your question is based on a misunderstanding, so it can likely be closed.

Comment: @Dono Yes, etymologically 調べ is from the original meaning of the verb. But as a verb, that meaning is rare and highly poetic today (I could not recall that meaning at first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question. I'm a Japanese, but I didn't know the answer. I searched on the Internet for your question. At last I found a proper answer at the URL site: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11112790666
I'll show you what it is as follows with adding furigana to kanji. Sorry to say, but I know this is a long answer and only in Japanese. So I recommend you to read the last part of the answer where there is the conclusion of it.

---

**Question**
 音楽{おんがく}で使{つか}う「しらべ」の語源{ごげん}は？  よく歌{うた}や音楽{おんがく}の世界{せかい}で「調{しら}べ」という言葉{ことば}を耳{みみ}にしますが、この言葉{ことば}にも語源{ごげん}はあるのでしょうか？ 普段{ふつう}一般的{いっぱんてき}に使{つか}われている「調{しら}べる」とは全{まった}く違{ちが}う意味{いみ}なのに、同{おな}じ漢字{かんじ}を使用{しよう}しているところに何{なに}か理由{りゆう}があるのかと思{おも}いまして。 調{しら}べてみても語源{ごげん}が見{み}当{あ}たらなかったので、どなたかご存知{ぞんじ}の方{かた}がいらっしゃいましたらご教授{きょうじゅ}の程{ほど}お願{ねが}い致{いた}します。

---

**Answer**
 古語{こご}辞典{じてん}などで「しらべる」(古形{こけい}は「しらぶ」)という単語{たんご}を見{み}ると、平安{へいあん}時代{じだい}以前{いぜん}は「楽器{がっき}を調律{ちょうりつ}する」「楽器{がっき}を鳴{な}らす」と言{い}う用法{ようほう}がほとんどです。「調査{ちょうさ}する」というような意味{いみ}で使用{しよう}される例{れい}は、中世{ちゅうせい}にならないと出{で}てきません。 
このことからもわかるように、「調{しら}ぶ」「調{しら}べ」は、元来{がんらい}、「楽器{がっき}の調子{ちょうし}を整{ととの}える」という意味{いみ}だったと考{かんが}えられます。「調子{ちょうし}を整{ととの}える」と言{い}う意味{いみ}から「いろいろなネタを照{て}らし合{あ}わせて吟味{ぎんみ}する」と言{い}う意味{いみ}が派生{はせい}し、「調査{ちょうさ}する」という意味{いみ}を持{も}つようになった物{もの}でしょう。 以上は、ヤマトコトバの世界{せかい}。次{つぎ}に、これが漢字{かんじ}の世界{せかい}と出会{であ}ったときに何{なに}が起{お}こったかを見{っみ}ておきます。 「調{ちょう}」という漢字{かんじ}は、元来{がんらい}、「しらべる」よりも「ととのう」「ととのえる」というニュアンスが強{つよ}い漢字{かんじ}と思{おも}われます。漢和{かんわ}辞典{じてん}で「調{ちょう}」という漢字{かんじ}を引{ひ}くと、「ととのう」「全体{ぜんたい}のバランス」と言{い}うような意味{いみ}や、そこから派生{はせい}した意味{いみ}がたくさん載{の}っており、「しらべる」を圧倒{あっとう}しています。「調{ちょう}」を含{ふく}む熟語{じゅくご}（調整{ちょうせい}・調理{ちょうり}・調和{ちょうわ}・調度品{ちょうどひん}…）などを見{み}ても、大部分{だいぶぶん}は、「ととのう」「ととのえる」という意味{いみ}です。「調査{ちょうさ}」と言{い}う熟語{じゅくご}があるにはありますが、「調査{ちょうさ}」の「色々{いろいろ}材料{ざいりょう}を吟味{ぎんみ}・判定{はんてい}する」という意味{いみ}は、むしろ、漢字{かんじ}「査{さ}」に由来{ゆらい}する物{もの}と見{み}ることができそうです。 そして、大昔{おおむかし}の日本人{にほんじん}は、「調{ちょう}」という漢字{かんじ}に出会{であ}ったとき、「調{ちょう}＝ととのう」と言{い}う意味{いみ}が、ヤマトコトバの「しらぶ」「しらべ」に一致{いっち}すると考{かんが}え、「調{ちょう}」の訓{くん}読{よ}みに、「しらぶ」「しらべ」を当{あ}てたのでしょう。

---

まとめると、
「しらべる」は、「楽器{がっき}の調子{ちょうし}を整{ととの}える」こそが本来{ほんらい}の意味{いみ}であり、「調査{ちょさ}する」はそこから派生{はせい}した意味{いみ}なのです。「音楽{おんがく}」「調子{ちょうし}の整{ととの}った音色{ねいろ}」という意味{いみ}の「しらべ」は、本来{ほんらい}の意味{いみ}を強{つよ}く残{のこ}した表現{ひょうげん}と言{い}えます。

**Free translation**　At first, the word 「verb しらぶ（old Japanese pronunciation）」had a meaning of "to tune a musical instrument", and 「nounしらべ」 had a meaning of "sounds made by a tuned musical instrument." After that, 「しらぶ」 got a meaning of "to compare various materials and examine them closely" derived from the original meaning of "to tune a musical instrument." And at last, it has come to have a meaning of "to investigateしらべる".

---

参考：日本国語大辞典・岩波古語辞典・改定新版漢字源